# Approximation of radial displacement

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry

I read, in a physics textbook, that  *a small displacement* $\Delta\mathbf{s}$ of a body -from point $P_i$ to $P_f$ in the image whose bad quality I apologise for: it is the first time I use Geogebra- with respect to a another punctiform body -point $O$ in the image- *makes the distance between the two body vary from $r$ to $r+\Delta r$*, where:$$\Delta r=|\Delta\mathbf{s}|\cos(\pi-\phi)=-|\Delta\mathbf{s}|\cos\phi.$$
where $\phi$ is the angle between $\Delta\mathbf{s}$ and the direction of the line passing through the two bodies and pointing towards the static body.

[image]

I suspect that the formula is not exact, but a sort of an asymptotic approximation, because such a $\Delta r$ seems to me to be the projection of $\Delta\mathbf{s}$ on the line passing through the other, static, punctiform body and the initial position of the moving body, i.e. it corresponds to $\overline{P_i Q}$ in my picture, while I think that the variation of the distance is rather $\overline{P_iR}$. Nevertheless, I cannot find a way to prove to myself how and why $\Delta r$ is approximated by $|\Delta\mathbf{s}|\cos(\pi-\phi)$. Thank you very much for any answer!

In order to specify further the context of the equality, I could say that it is then used to say the work made by a central force $\mathbf{F}$ directed toward the fixed punctiform body is $\mathbf{F}\cdot\Delta \mathbf{s}=F|\Delta\mathbf{s}|\cos\phi =-F\Delta r$ and therefore such work only depends upon $\Delta r$.

Comment: What is $\phi$?

Comment: @ArpanBanerjee Thank you for noticing that I had forgotten to specify that! Edited and tried to make a picture to better explain my thoughts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the cosine theorem:
$$
|OP_f|^2=|OP_i|^2+|P_iP_f|^2-2·|OP_i|·|P_iP_f|·\cos(\angle OP_iP_f)
$$
or in the other names of the lengths
\begin{align}
(r+Δr)^2&=r^2+|Δs|^2-2·r·|Δs|·\cosϕ
\\[1em]
Δr&=\sqrt{r^2+|Δs|^2-2·r·|Δs|·\cosϕ}-r
\\
&=-\frac{2·r·\cosϕ-|Δs|}{r+\sqrt{r^2+|Δs|^2-2·r·|Δs|·\cosϕ}}·|Δs|
\\
&=-\frac{2·\cosϕ-|Δs|/r}{1+\sqrt{1+((|Δs|/r)^2-2·(|Δs|/r)·\cosϕ}}·|Δs|
\\
&=-\frac{\cosϕ-\frac12·|Δs|/r}{1-\frac12·\cosϕ·(|Δs|/r)+O((|Δs|/r)^2)}·|Δs|
\\[0.5em]
&=-\cosϕ·|Δs|+\frac12·\sin^2ϕ·|Δs|^2/r+O(|Δs|^3/r^2)
\end{align}
If $|Δs|$ is very small against $r$ then the higher order terms can be ommitted.

Comment: Yes, that is one way to write it. Another is that $Δr=−\cosϕ⋅|Δs|+O((|Δs|/r)^2)$, which is a bit stronger.

Comment: It is $$\frac12(1+\sqrt{1-2(|Δs|/r)\cosϕ+…})=\frac12(1+1+\frac12(-2(|Δs|/r)\cosϕ+…)+…)\\=1-\frac12(|Δs|/r)\cosϕ+…$$ The cancellation is by the factor $2r$. Using $\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac12 x-\frac18 x^2+\frac1{16}x^3\mp…$.

Comment: Understood: the Taylor expansion $\sqrt{1+x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{1/2}{k}x^k,x\in(-1,1)$. $\aleph_1$ thanks!